# jQuery - On escape, close window if overlay not open

Tags: javascript, jquery

When the escape key is pressed, I would like to close a child window, but first check for open overlays. If an overlay is open and the escape key is pressed, I only want the overlay to close. If the user presses escape again, I want it to close the child window.

So, I first need to check whether an overlay is open. All my overlays have a class of `.simpleOverlay` and a close button with the class `.closeOverlayBtn`, so I thought of having a function that checks if that class has focus, before closing the window, like so:

```
if (e.keyCode == 27) { // "Esc" Key
   if ( $('.simpleOverlay').is(':focus') ) {
       $('.closeOverlayBtn').trigger('click');
   }
   else {
       window.close();
   }    
   return(false);
}
```

But this is not happening!! If I replace the `.trigger` line with an `alert()`, I get alerted when the overlay is closed and open, not good!

Is this the right way to go about this or am I completely missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
if (e.keyCode == 27) { // "Esc" Key

   if ( $('.simpleOverlay').is(':visible') ) {
       $('.closeOverlayBtn').click();
   }
   else {
       window.close();
   }    
   return(false);
}
```

Comment: Perfect thanks! I read elsewhere I can use :focus but for some reason, not in my case. I'm testing it on Chrome.

Comment: Awesome! Glad I didn't have to figure out how to set this up in JSFiddle. =D

Comment: Why are you calling `.preventDefault()`?

Answer (score 0):

## Use modern JS

```
if (e.key === "Escape") {
   if ($('.simpleOverlay').is(':visible')) {
       $('.closeOverlayBtn').click();
   }
   else {
       window.close();
   }    
   return false;
}
```